# keycode of log keys of MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, keycode

I need to figure out the key code of log keys of Mac(ctrl, shift etc) or need to know how to track this log key press event...

basically I am converting mac key codes to equivalent windows key code...how can I do this?

```
+ (unsigned int) winKeyValueForKey:(unsigned int) macKeyValue{
unsigned int mapTable[128];
mapTable[0] = 0;
mapTable[1] = 0;
mapTable[2] = 0;
mapTable[3] = 0;
mapTable[4] = 0;
mapTable[5] = 0;
mapTable[6] = 0;
mapTable[7] = 0;
mapTable[8] = 0;
mapTable[9] = 0;
mapTable[10] = 0;
mapTable[11] = 0;
mapTable[12] = 0;
mapTable[13] = 0;
mapTable[14] = 0;
mapTable[15] = 0;
mapTable[16] = 0;
mapTable[17] = 0;
mapTable[18] = 0;
mapTable[19] = 0;
mapTable[20] = 0;
mapTable[21] = 0;
mapTable[22] = 0;
mapTable[23] = 0;
mapTable[24] = 0;
mapTable[25] = 0;
mapTable[26] = 0;
mapTable[27] = 0;
mapTable[28] = 0;
mapTable[29] = 0;
mapTable[30] = 0;
mapTable[31] = 0;
mapTable[32] = 0;
mapTable[33] = 0;
mapTable[34] = 0;
mapTable[35] = 0;
mapTable[36] = 13; //SHOEB
mapTable[37] = 0;
mapTable[38] = 0;
mapTable[39] = 0;
mapTable[40] = 0;
mapTable[41] = 0;
mapTable[42] = 0;
mapTable[43] = 0;
mapTable[44] = 0;
mapTable[45] = 0;
mapTable[46] = 0;
mapTable[47] = 0;
mapTable[48] = 0;
mapTable[49] = 0;
mapTable[50] = 0;
mapTable[51] = 0;
mapTable[52] = 0;
mapTable[53] = 0;
mapTable[54] = 0;
mapTable[55] = 0;
mapTable[56] = 0;
mapTable[57] = 0;
mapTable[58] = 0;
mapTable[59] = 0;
mapTable[60] = 0;
mapTable[61] = 0;
mapTable[62] = 0;
mapTable[63] = 0;
mapTable[64] = 0;
mapTable[65] = 0;
mapTable[66] = 0;
mapTable[67] = 0;
mapTable[68] = 0;
mapTable[69] = 0;
mapTable[70] = 0;
mapTable[71] = 0;
mapTable[72] = 0;
mapTable[73] = 0;
mapTable[74] = 0;
mapTable[75] = 0;
mapTable[76] = 0;
mapTable[77] = 0;
mapTable[78] = 0;
mapTable[79] = 0;
mapTable[80] = 0;
mapTable[81] = 0;
mapTable[82] = 0;
mapTable[83] = 0;
mapTable[84] = 0;
mapTable[85] = 0;
mapTable[86] = 0;
mapTable[87] = 0;
mapTable[88] = 0;
mapTable[89] = 0;
mapTable[90] = 0;
mapTable[91] = 0;
mapTable[92] = 0;
mapTable[93] = 0;
mapTable[94] = 0;
mapTable[95] = 0;
mapTable[96] = 0;
mapTable[97] = 0;
mapTable[98] = 0;
mapTable[99] = 0;
mapTable[100] = 0;
mapTable[101] = 0;
mapTable[102] = 0;
mapTable[103] = 0;
mapTable[104] = 0;
mapTable[105] = 0;
mapTable[106] = 0;
mapTable[107] = 0;
mapTable[108] = 0;
mapTable[109] = 0;
mapTable[110] = 0;
mapTable[111] = 0;
mapTable[112] = 0;
mapTable[113] = 0;
mapTable[114] = 0;
mapTable[115] = 0;
mapTable[116] = 0;
mapTable[117] = 0;
mapTable[118] = 0;
mapTable[119] = 0;
mapTable[120] = 0;
mapTable[121] = 0;
mapTable[122] = 0;  
mapTable[123] = 37;
mapTable[124] = 39;
mapTable[125] = 40;
mapTable[126] = 38;
mapTable[127] = 0;  
return mapTable[macKeyValue];
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Control, Shift, Command, and Option keys on OS X do not generate `NSKeyDown/kCGEventKeyDown` events. Instead, you can receive a `NSFlagsChanged/kCGEventFlagsChanged` event.

That is, "typically" if the user typed **Option-T** and you are scanning `keyDown` events, you will only see a "T" event, which includes the fact that the option key is "modifying" it.

If you want to get `flagsChanged` events, you can receive that with an event tap, or in an `NSResponder` somewhere. The `flagsChanged` event tells you the new collection of modifiers (shift/command/etc). In that case, it is helpful to store a local copy of the previous modifiers so you can see which particular key went down or up.